# Stop NSTimer when x coördinate equals 0

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have the following code:

```
CharacterMoving = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(CharacterMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This basically starts the timer, and runs the CharacterMoving method every 0.01 seconds. That all works nice and smooth.

Then, I have this code:

```
-(void)CharacterMoving{
    Character.center = CGPointMake(Character.center.x - 1, Character.center.y);
}
```

This makes the character image move to the left, and this works smoothly. So when the image reaches the edge of the screen, I want the image to stop moving, and run a different method. I tried doing this with the following code:

```
-(void)CharacterMoving{
    Character.center = CGPointMake(Character.center.x - 1, Character.center.y);
    if (Character.center.x == 0) {
        [Character invalidate];
        [self DifferentVoid];
    }
}

-(void)DifferentMethod{
    //do something here
}
```

Unfortunately, the DifferentMethod doesn't run, and the image doesn't stop moving when it hits the edge of the screen. Thanks in advance for helping me out!

EDIT:
I've found this solution. Changing the '==' into '<' solves the problem.

Comment: after Character.center you can try to print what is the center, like: NSLog(@"character center x = %f",Character.center.x);  maybe Character.center is never 0 .. and why you call [Character invalidate] ? If you want stop the Timer you should do [CharacterMoving invalidate];

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added NSLog(@"character center x = %f",Character1.center.x);. The x coördinate does decrease to 0 and below. I changed [Character invalidate]; to [CharacterMoving invalidate]; and I'm unfortunately still stuck with the same problem.

Comment: .. why Character1.center.x and not Character.center.x ? and I suggest you do not use the same name for two different things? Like NSTimer and void

Comment: As llario said you are strangely using and Object : Character and Character1 which is pretty strange I think. Are you sure about this ?

Comment: Yeah, it's a typo, it has to be Character.center.x - 1, Character.center.y. Sorry for that.

Comment: If you want help, stop using capital letters for the names of instances.

Comment: Then good if you want your method to be called then you should call it I guess --> you put `[self DifferentVoid];` instead of `[self DifferentMethod];` no ?  or what is this `DifferentVoid`?
Moreover `[Character invalidate];` should be `[CharacterMoving invalidate];`

Answer (score 2):

You've got this:

```
[Character invalidate];
[self DifferentVoid];
```

so it's no surprise that a method called `-DifferentMethod` doesn't run -- you're not calling it. Also, you're sending `-invalidate` to `Character`, but the timer that you started is (judging by the preceding code) called `CharacterMoving`.

**Aside:** I see that you also have a method called `-CharacterMoving`. It'd be a good idea to avoid using the same names for your variables and your methods. Also, you'll help yourself and avoid confusing others if you follow the normal [Objective-C naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH).

Comment: precisely what I said in the comment so +1 :3

Comment: @CladClad Ha! I said it first! ;-) But +1 to you too.